# Android HttpUrlConnection erroor handling

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm developing an Android app which works with server. I have POST request (using HttpURLConnection). Code is:

```
//setting URL to HttpURLConnection conn
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(14000);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : paramList.entrySet())
    builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

DataOutputStream  os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
responseCode = conn.getResponseCode(); // IOException!
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

In case of error I need to show exact error message, for instance, "Connection timeout", or "Read timeout", or "Authorization problems" (for 401 status), etc.
How can I handle:

- Connection timeout?
- ReadTimeout?

And how can I get response code if it throws an IOException if server responses 4xx status? I read several questions here, but I didn't understand, how can I handle timeout errors and how can I get response code in case of IOException.

Comment: What is the reason for `IOException` ? post the stack trace.

Comment: i have a suggestion for you, go for retrofit,  its very easy and 10 times faster than your native code  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: When server returns 401 response code, getResponseCode() method throws IOException.

Comment: use retrofit or volley libs instead they do all the work for you and beter

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but now I'm using HttpURLConnection. 
Also I've got a suggestion to use okHttp library :)